# XML formatting Indentation Tags Matching - Linux

Tags: xml, linux, bash, ubuntu, xml-formatting

I have an XML file whose format is quite compressed and all tags are stick together like

```
<PersonalData><IndividualDetails><Title>Mr</Title><Gender>Male</Gender><FirstName>Hae</FirstName><Surname>JONES</Surname><Occupation>Banker</Occupation><DateofBirth>4/6/76</DateofBirth><LastKnownAddress></LastKnownAddress><LastKnownPostCode>00145</LastKnownPostCode><OtherNames></OtherNames></IndividualDetails><OccupationDetails><Company>SD Bank</Company><CompanyAddress>Sunset Boulevard NY</CompanyAddress><ContactNo>335698457</ContactNo></OccupationDetails></PersonalData>
```

Is there any command in shell that can properly format the tags. If not indentation only adding the tags to their own lines can also solve my problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
xmllint --format <your-xml-file>
```

example

```
$ cat test.xml
<a><b>c</b></a>
$ xmllint --format test.xml
<a>
  <b>c</b>
</a>
$ xmllint --format test.xml > test.formatted.xml
$ cat test.formatted.xml
<a>
  <b>c</b>
</a>
$
```

Comment: This is not working on the Actual file. The file size of my XML is approx 583 MB. The Format option works on a small size file but when i apply this on actual file the Bash Kills the operation. Any idea for formatting BIG files, in chunks or so...

Comment: 583 MB? Maybe you should implement your own SAX handler for indentation.

Comment: And how can i do that. Just guide me in this

Comment: One thing to bear in mind with the `xmllint` approach is that it won't preserver the exact original text. eg. `<a></a>` will be transformed into `<a/>`. Technically this is correct, but it may catch you out if you aren't expecting it.

Comment: Did you implement a solution for handling big files?

Comment: At that size you might need to add the `--stream` option.

Answer (score 10):

```
tidy -xml -i -q
```

-xml - specify the input is well formed XML

-q - suppress nonessential output

-i - indent element content

tidy can work with files and stdin/stdout

```
echo '<a><b>c</b></a>' | tidy -xml -i -q
```

will produce

```
    <a>
      <b>c</b>
    </a>
```